# Can't start docker due to mysql process not stopped correctly. Mysql is running somewhere

Tags: mysql, docker

I was trying to run a docker image which used Mysql port 3306.No matter how I tried I was getting this error.

```
Starting docker containers
restarting mysql
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mysql (33092fa3c472ffa15ba1f5b482a235f50c1e5db138d69eb4aab55228d367960a): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated
Error: failed to start containers: mysql
make: *** [start-docker] Error 1
```

I tried to kill the process by looking other stack overflow posts with no success.

Tried:

```
lsof -i tcp:3306
sudo netstat -lpn |grep :3306
```

And bunch of other stuff. But when I do a  `ps -ax | grep mysql`, it showMySQLql is running somewhere.

Comment: Can you please provide docker run command ?

Comment: Its a custom image which uses mysql

Comment: I want to see what you have exposed in Port and also it possible that when you restart the container or SQL inside container service already running

Comment: 3306 was exposed. And i was starting the container for the first time. So I don’t think that could be the case. What happened was there was already a mysql process running on my machine which was not getting detected. But i could see it running when i did a ps -ax.

Comment: What is your -p option ? If it is 3306:3306 and it is highly possible that your local machine - host has SQL installed.

Comment: That’s exactly what had happened. I guess i was not clear in my above comment.

Comment: In that case it would be nice if you expose SQL to some another port on host machine. Like -p 3307:3306. From host you can access it using port 3307 but if you have another docker app then it can use 3306 for internal communication between docker container.

Answer (score 0):

> ps -l

gave me the description and location of my **PID** when I do a PS command.

```
UID   PID  PPID        F CPU PRI NI       SZ    RSS WCHAN     S             ADDR TTY           TIME CMD
```

> ps -ljax | grep mysql

Gave me the actual PID of MySQL running **PID**

> sudo kill -9 111

did the trick for me.